# How to get attribute from variable product?

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

I have variable product with attribute URL that is used for variations.

I need to display it on page but I dont know how. I tried many ways but nothing was OK. For example this code:

```
echo get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], 'attribute_pa_url', true);
```

returns url like "httpwww-example-comsometthingsomethingelse" instead of "http://www.example.com/sometthing/somethingelse"

Any hint what I should do?

Comment: Check the value in the database first. I tried you code and this seems to work fine if the value is stored correctly in DB.

Comment: In DB I see this value in two places - wp_postmeta table and wp_terms table. In Postmeta it is stored badly, in Terms it is OK. I'm not sure why is it in two places but in product edit page it looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

That worked:

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_color';
$meta = get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
$term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);
echo $term->name;
```

Thanks to [Reigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251986/reigel)!